# String substitution/String formating in Haxe

Tags: haxe

A feature that - most often - is quite helpful is string substitution/string formating. For example one of the following commands:

```
"Hi my name is %s and I'm %s years old" % ("Derp", 12)
```

or

```
"Hi my name is {0} and I'm {1} years old".format("Derp", 12)
```

will be evaluated to

```
Hi my name is Derp and I'm 12 years old
```

in python. Is there a (predefined) way to do something similar in Haxe?

Comment: Basic Haxe features are well documented. The answer to your question is the [top Google result for "haxe string formatting"](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=haxe%20string%20formatting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup.

It's called [String Interpolation](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-string-interpolation.html) in Haxe.

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent of this:

```
var name = "Mark";
var age = 31;
var message = 'Hi my name is $name and Im $age years old';
trace(message);
```

String interpolation however is a compile time feature, which basically translates it to:
`"Hi my name is " + name + " and I'm " + age + " years old"`

If you use dynamic text (eg. translations and stuff) and want the format you proposed then you could use a regexp like this:

```
using Main.StringUtil;

class Main {
    public static function main() {
        var message = "hi my name is {0} and I'm {1} years old".format(["mark", 31]);
        trace(message);
    }
}

class StringUtil {
    public static function format(value:String, values:Array<Any>) {
        var ereg:EReg = ~/(\{(\d{1,2})\})/g;
        while (ereg.match(value)) {
            value = ereg.matchedLeft() + values[Std.parseInt(ereg.matched(2))] + ereg.matchedRight();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Try it yourself online: https://try.haxe.org/#381c8

> The `using` at the top of the class allows to use a string as mixin `"".format()` (this is called [static extension](https://haxe.org/manual/lf-static-extension.html) in Haxe).

---

**Update:** without regular expressions you can just do this:

```
using StringTools;
using Main.StringUtil;

class Main {
    public static function main() {
        var message = "hi my name is {0} and I'm {1} years old".format(["mark", 31]);
        trace(message);
    }
}

class StringUtil {
    public static function format(value:String, values:Array<Any>) {
        for (i in 0...values.length) {
            value = value.replace('{$i}', values[i]);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Try it yourself online: https://try.haxe.org/#8A17A

Comment: Note that the variables can change at runtime with the built in way of doing it. It was a bit unclear as the second part of your answer sounded like it was a work around for it being compile time only, but is only for using brackets instead of the dollar sign.